# Where we can found the source code of Firebase (if it's available)

Tags: firebase

Where we can found the source code of Firebase (if it's available) ? Especially the source code of Firebase messaging and Firebase common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is a combination of Cloud-based services and client-side SDKs for various platforms. None of these pieces are currently open-source.

There are a bunch of add-on libraries from Firebase, which are open-source. You can find them on Github: https://github.com/firebase/